# Do programming languages with access modifiers perform any optimizations based on access level?

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, compilation, programming-languages

Straightforward from the question.

Which, if any, language compilers perform optimization or compilation quirks when access modifiers are present on a symbol, keyword, etc.?

As a bonus: Are there optimizations that language compilers without access modifiers can do that one with them cannot? (In other words, do access modifiers ever prevent optimizations for the sake of the programmer's control)

**EDIT**

To be precise, I'm specifically referring to keywords like public, private, and protected, or some similar construct.

Answer (score 1):

In OO languages, method invocations are dynamically dispatched. If the compiler/runtime can figure out that there exists only one implementation of the method, and that the method won't change, it can perform more aggressive optimization.

From that point of view, `private` methods should be easier to optimize. Similarly, methods that belong to a class that is `sealed` are also easier to optimize.

I say "easier" becaues modern compilers/runtimes optimize lots of things anyway, but they need to rely on guards to make sure that the optimization are "deoptimized" if some assumptions becomes invalid. See [this blog post](http://briangoetz.blogspot.ch/2006/12/reader-mail-urban-performance-legends.html) from Brian Goetz.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, languages don't perform optimizations, compilers do. Therefore the answer (usually) depends on the compiler implementation and on the compiler's options that you specify.

Most C++ compilers perform a significant amount of optimization depending on the **const** keyword: they pre-compute everything that can be computed at compile time, etc.

For example, consider the code inside the function "fraction":

```
const double yet_another_pi = 3.14;
double denominator() {
    return sqrt( 2*yet_another_pi );
}
double fraction( double numerator )
{
    return numerator / denominator();
}
```

This code will result on **most** compilers in a single **multiplication** of numerator by the precomputed reciprocal of sqrt(2*3.14).

Without the const keyword the same code would result in multiplication by 2 and a square root inside the function "denominator" followed by division in the function "fraction".

---

There are many other examples of modifiers that improve optimization. Some of them (such as enforcing certain alignment) have platform dependent effects.

---

If you are asking whether the **availability** of access modifiers inhibit optimization the answer is "no".

If you are asking whether incorrect **usage** of access modifiers can inhibit optimization the answer is "yes": if you apply **volatile** keyword to every variable in your code performance will go to drain because volatile variables cannot be optimized in registers.

---

**EDIT:** based on the comments to this answer, the question may have been about private/protected/public keywords. I am not aware of any optimization related to these keywords, except for a related Java's keyword "final".

Comment: I don't think `const` and `volatile` are access modifiers, neither in the common vocabulary nor in legalese (they're "qualifiers" in C and C++, and "modifiers" in Java). We'd have to ask OP, but I think the question is about `private`, `protected`, `public`.

Comment: The question is indeed about the latter mentioned modifiers (public, private, protected).